# How to avoid "class path resource [...] cannot be opened because it does not exist" in a spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, classpath

I have a small spring boot application which ships an application.properties in src/main/resources - that works like a charm.
The user should now be able to configure some more stuff (2 credentials), so i expect a file called "matrixregistration.config" in the classpath.
Unfortunately, this file is not found, no matter where it is.
The application is distributed with the gradle spring boot task bootDistZip.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:matrixregistration.config")
@Validated
public class MatrixRegistrationConfiguration {

    private String sharedSecret;
    private String registrationPassword;
...
```

My distribution package is on the server at /home/matrix/matrixregistration-boot, with a "bin" and a "lib" folder.
I would expect that when i put the configuration into this directory and start the application with ./bin/matrixregistration, the classpath should include "." and find the configuration. But it does not. The configuration file is there.

The exception:

```
matrix@myhost:~/matrixregistration-boot$ ./bin/matrixregistration

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

2019-04-21 10:04:47.332  INFO 25962 --- [           main] matrixregistration.Application           : Starting Application on myhost.de with PID 25962 (/home/matrix/matrixregistration-boot/lib/matrixregistration.jar started by matrix in /home/matrix/matrixregistration-boot)
2019-04-21 10:04:47.342  INFO 25962 --- [           main] matrixregistration.Application           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-04-21 10:04:47.804  WARN 25962 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [matrixregistration.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [matrixregistration.config] cannot be opened because it does not exist
2019-04-21 10:04:48.237 ERROR 25962 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [matrixregistration.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [matrixregistration.config] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:705) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:531) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.4.RELEASE]
        at matrixregistration.Application.main(Application.java:10) ~[classes!/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[matrixregistration.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[matrixregistration.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[matrixregistration.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[matrixregistration.jar:na]
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [matrixregistration.config] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:159) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:99) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:59) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePropertySource.<init>(ResourcePropertySource.java:67) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.DefaultPropertySourceFactory.createPropertySource(DefaultPropertySourceFactory.java:37) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processPropertySource(ConfigurationClassParser.java:452) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:191) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:295) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:199) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Can someone tell me how i can configure that task or how i should do it to get it working? Thanks!

edit: with
@PropertySource("file:./matrixregistration.properties")
it works.
The user can configure the application which looks in "." for matrixregistration.properties

Comment: Search for `matrixregistration.conf` not `matrixregistration.config`

Comment: @user7294900
Sorry, typo. The file is called "matrixregistration.config", in the code and is on the filesystem with same name.
I will rename it to ".conf" after this problem is solved. Guess that makes sense, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and solved it by "clean build".

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I think you must put the absolute path in @PropertySource("classpath:matrixregistration.config").

For example:

@PropertySource("classpath:path/from/src/matrixregistration.config")

I wait that it help you.

Comment: I want the user to be able to configure that. I found a solution. I use now 
@PropertySource("file:./matrixregistration.properties")

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same error when my file name was with `_`. Removing underscore in the filename fixed for me.

My file name was `my_file_name.csv` changing it to `my-file-name.csv` works.